# Is it possible to use a link rule reference in a lookahead fashion?

Tags: peg, textx

I am attempting to use textx in order to parse a language similar to SQL. I would like to use link rule references in order to reference aliases before they are declared.

I get an "Unknown Object of "Foo" of class "Bar"" error when attempting to do this sort of forward reference.

The simplest example showing what I would like to parse is given below:

```sql
SELECT B.c
FROM A AS B
```

In this case I would like the `B` in `B.c` to refer to the alias defined afterwards (`B` in `A AS B`).

EDIT

Looking into it further it seems that the grammar I have parses the simple example I gave above just fine, but runs into problems when I attempt to use a nested query in the `FROM` clause.

Here's the grammar I'm using:

```
Expression: Query | Atomic | Tuple;

Query:
    'SELECT' selections+=Selection[',']
    'FROM' from=From
;

Selection[noskipws]:
    /\s*/
    source=[SourceAlias] ('.' source_selectors+=ID['.'])?  /\s*/ ('AS' /\s*/ alias=ID)?
    /\s*/
;

From:
        (source=DataSource | '(' Query ')') 'AS' alias=SourceAlias
;

DataSource: source_name=ID '.' source_attributes+=ID['.'];

SourceAlias: name=ID;

Tuple: '(' atoms+=Atomic[','] ')';

Atomic: NUMBER | STRING | BOOL;
```

And Here's an example that my grammar fails on, with error `"test.qql:2:14: error: Unknown object "B" of class "SourceAlias"`:

```
SELECT inner.o AS outer
FROM (SELECT B.huh AS aha FROM A.b AS B) AS inner
```

Comment: Reference resolving comes after the parsing is done and objects are constructed so it should work regardless of the position of the target object. Could you extend your question to show a relevant piece of grammar you are trying?

Comment: @IgorDejanović That's good to know. I actually realized that it's nested queries that are causing issues so I updated the question to include the grammar I'm using and the nested query it fails on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the `From` rule the `Query` match is not being assigned to anything, so it is being discarded and thus the references in the inner query are discarded. Here's the updated `From` rule:

```
From:
        (source=DataSource | '(' query=Query ')') 'AS' alias=SourceAlias
;
```